# How to SUM() columns based on other column values SQL

Tags: sql

I have some data of people betting. The bets can be 'won', 'lost' or 'pending'. I want to get the amount people have bet and the amount they have won.

The amount won should be amount * odds BUT if it was a bonus bet (1) it will  subtract the original stake (amount) from the total. Bonus bets do not include the original stake in the total win amount.

Also amountbet should not include the amount from Bonus bets as they are more tokens then lost money. Hopefully in one SQL.

I have got this far....

```
SELECT *, SUM(amount) AS amountbet 
FROM bets 
WHERE club = 2 
  AND result <> 'pending'
  AND bonus = 0
GROUP BY user
```

And I also have this SQL statement

```
SELECT *, SUM(amount * odds - (amount * bonus)) AS amountwon 
FROM bets 
WHERE club = 2 
  AND result = 'won' 
GROUP BY user
```

So if it is a bonus bet it will subtract amount or it will subtract amount * 0 i.e. = 0

I can probably work around if not but if there is an elegant way I would like to try.

Thanks

The DB table looks like this

```
ID | user | amount | odds | result | bonus | club |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CASE` expressions inside the `SUM()` to apply the filtering you want.

```
SELECT
  user,
  SUM(                                   amount    )  AS total_amount,
  SUM(CASE WHEN result  = 'won'     THEN amount END)  AS amount_won,
  SUM(CASE WHEN result <> 'pending' THEN amount END)  AS amount_bet
FROM
  bets 
WHERE
  club = 2 
GROUP BY
  user
```

There's no `ELSE` in those, which implicitly does `ELSE NULL`, and then `NULL`s are effectively ignored by aggregates.

Comment: Sorry i completely botched this question after I ran your answer on my DB. I updated what I need. Sorry its much more confusing

Comment: @ThomasByy Just put the calculation where this answer has `THEN amount`; a case expression can return the result of any calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `conditional aggregation` using a `case` expression,

```
SELECT User,
  sum (case when result in ('won','lost') then amount end) as AmountBet,
  sum (case when result='won' then amount end) as AmountWon
FROM bets 
WHERE club = 2 
GROUP BY user
```